# Graph# Visual Studio extension Xaml Exception

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I make the tool window extension for Visual Studio 2012. In the extension i try to display some simple graphs. I get the strange error: XamlParserException. The method or operation is not implemented.
Here is my Xaml:

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:graphsharp="clr-namespace:GraphSharp.Controls;assembly=GraphSharp.Controls"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Microsoft.NewGraph" x:Class="Microsoft.NewGraph.MyControl"
        x:Name="root">
<Grid>
    <graphsharp:GraphLayout x:Name="graphLayout" Graph="{Binding ElementName=root,Path=GraphToVisualize}" />
</Grid>
```

And here is the code:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    private IBidirectionalGraph<object, IEdge<object>> _graphToVisualize;


    public IBidirectionalGraph<object, IEdge<object>> GraphToVisualize
    {
        get { return _graphToVisualize; }
    }


    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

If i use the same code for WPF Application everything works fine. 
What can  it be that does not work for the VS extension?

Comment: 1 - Post the stack trace. 2 - NotImplementedException occurs in user code, so I don't know what graph# is, but its probably not ready for vs2012.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to give an answer to your question, because you did not provide stack trace information. But first of all you should check that all dependencies are added to the vsix package (means no assembly is missing).

I had an issue regarding a WPF control library these days, and adding the following attribute to the package class did the fix...

```
[ProvideBindingPath]
class MyPackage : Package ...
```

I guess, that this will fix your problem (-:

Comment: you did save my life